# jQuery targeting this and class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to extract data from a table, more specifically a class within a column.

```
value = jQuery(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td').text();
```

Within this cell, there are two classes. 
One called:

```
.amount
```

and another called:

```
.currency
```

I need to target the one called .amount.

I have tried following code, but it gives me the amount and currency.

```
value = jQuery(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td').find('.amount').text();
```

What am I doing wrong?

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('input').on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        productName = jQuery(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
        value = jQuery(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td.amount').text();
        jQuery(".spiseseddel ul").append('<li>' + productName + value + '</li>');
    } else {
        productName = jQuery(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
        jQuery('.spiseseddel ul li').filter(function() {
            return jQuery.text([this]) === productName;
    }).remove();
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="amount">25,00
        <span class="currency">DKK</span>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-name">product name
    </td>
    <td class="add-to-cart">
    <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Post the HTML you want to use this with please

Comment: Which element is `this`?

Comment: I have added the HTML, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()` in the cell you want to target, not the current cell.

```
value = jQuery(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td').find(".amount").text();
```

Comment: `this` will not be the *current cell*, otherwise `closest('td')` would probably return nothing (unless it's a table in a table).

Comment: I assume `this` is something inside the current cell, like a button, checkbox, or link.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify which td class you need:

```
value = jQuery(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td.amount').text();
```

Comment: He says `.amount` and `.currency` are within the cell, not the cell itself.

Comment: `.prev('td.amount')` doesn't search for a td with that class. It returns the previous element if it matches the selector `td.amount`, otherwise it returns nothing.

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry for confusing.